# 'JModuleHelper' is deprecated in Joomla 4 and what is its equivalent

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x

I am using the below joomla code in my custom component.

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_mycustommodule');
$moduleParams = new Joomla\Registry\Registry($module->params);
```

It seems 'JModuleHelper' is deprecated from Joomla 4 and would like to know what is the equivalent in Joomla 4 style of coding.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fully qualified class name which is `Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper`.

To get this information in your IDE, you can run `build/stubGenerator.php` script via PHP command line. This will generate a stub file of deprecated class aliases and the new classes to use. This is how it looks in VS code:

[image]